# How to handle click on “Download key” button in selenium web driver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am not sure what `find_element_by_*` I should use with respect to below "inspect element" to click on the download button. I am new to selenium still dealing with basics.

```
<a href="#" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['activationpage3'],'activationpage3:j_id_id21,activationpage3:j_id_id21','');}return false">Download Key File</a>
```

Comment: I would recommend reading some guides/tutorials, and the docs. This kind of question ultimately has very little value both to the asker and to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Download Key File']").click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Download Key File** as it is an **`<a>`** node you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download Key File"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Download Key File"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='activationpage3']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'activationpage3') and contains(., 'Download Key File')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```